# Avoiding initialize method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am writing the Ruby program found below

```
class Animal
  attr_reader :name, :age

  def name=(value)
    if value == ""
      raise "Name can't be blank!"
    end
    @name = value
  end

  def age=(value)
    if value < 0
      raise "An age of #{value} isn't valid!"
    end
    @age = value
  end

  def talk
    puts "#{@name} says Bark!"
  end

  def move(destination)
    puts "#{@name} runs to the #{destination}."
  end

  def report_age
    puts "#{@name} is #{@age} years old."
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
end

class Bird < Animal
end

class Cat < Animal
end

whiskers = Cat.new("Whiskers")
fido = Dog.new("Fido")
polly = Bird.new("Polly")
polly.age = 2
polly.report_age
fido.move("yard")
whiskers.talk
```

But when I run it, it gives this error:

```
C:/Users/akathaku/mars2/LearningRuby/Animal.rb:32:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Users/akathaku/mars2/LearningRuby/Animal.rb:32:in `new'
    from C:/Users/akathaku/mars2/LearningRuby/Animal.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

My investigations shows that I should create objects like this

```
whiskers = Cat.new("Whiskers")
```

Then there should be an `initialize` method in my code which will initialize the instance variable with the value "Whiskers".

But if I do so then what is the purpose of attribute accessors that I am using? Or is it like that we can use only one and if I have to use attribute accessors then I should avoid initializing the instance variables during object creation.

Comment: Please use two-spaces for indentation and ensure that code is readable - https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout.

Comment: @WandMaker Sure i will take care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initialize` is the constructor of your class and it runs when objects are *created*.

Attribute accessors are used to read or modify attributes of *existing* objects.

Parameterizing the constructor(s) gives you the advantage of having a short and neat way to give values to your object's properties.

```
whiskers = Cat.new("Whiskers")
```

looks better and it's easier to write than

```
whiskers = Cat.new
whiskers.name = "Whiskers"
```

The code for `initialize` in this case should look like

```
class Animal
  ...
  def initialize(a_name)
    name = a_name
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: You may want to show example of `initialize` for achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

All `attr_reader :foo` does is define the method `def foo; @foo; end`. Likewise, `attr_writer :foo` does so for `def foo=(val); @foo = val; end`. They do not do assume anything about how you want to structure your `initialize` method, and you would have to add something like

```
def initialize(foo)
  @foo = foo
end
```

Though, if you want to reduce boilerplate code for attributes, you can use something like [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html) or [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus).

Answer (score 0):

You should define a method right below your class name, something like

```
def initialize name, age
@name = name
@age = age
end
```